# Vlookup formula returning multipal columns of data from 2nd tab/sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking for some help with formula to match value in sheet 2 column A to column A sheet 1 and return the matching value from sheet 1 along with the 13 cells in the same row to the right of the matching value in column A sheet 1.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

Answer (score 0):

just repeat the VLOOKUP in the next N columns, with the exact same parameters, except the column # counting up

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use LOOKUP. Put in B2:

```
=LOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,Sheet1!B$1:B$7)
```

And then copy down and right...

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That did work.  I was trying to return multiple column values in the same row using one formula in column B sheet2.  I have seen it done but cannot complete the formula without error.

Comment: having arrays of text, excel worksheet functions are designet to pick one and will not allow you to easily concatenate them... while google sheets support `Join`, excel itself only knows this inside of VBA... knowing that, you could write an UDF to do so, but normally ppl dount want to go the VBA-way for just one action... (while it can be done pretty easy)

Comment: Unfortunately macros is about as close to VBA as I get.  Thanks